# Dynamically adding and removing Event listeners

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I added a tap listener to a div in a custom element using

```
var nicediv = document.getElementById('nicediv');
nicediv.addEventListener('tap',this.listenerfunc.bind(this),false);
```

This is successful but I am unable to remove the event listener. This didn't work.

```
nicediv.removeEventListener('tap',this.listenerfunc);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try this. function removeEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler) {
 if (elem.removeEventListener) 
    elem.removeEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
 if (elem.detachEvent)
    elem.detachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}

Comment: I just logged in console to see which is present. elem.removeEventListener is valid and resulted in `function removeEventListener() { [native code] }`. But detachEvent is undefined. So what I used is fine. The false value for useCapture in removeEventListener should be false by default as I am using latest chrome. But I tried that as well anyway. Didn't work. This must be polymer related.

Comment: yeah. this should work but maybe polymer is doing something here. detachEvent is for older browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the listening function isn't the same function you are attempting to remove. By adding `.bind(this)`, you have altered the function. In other words, `this.listenerfunc` !== `this.listenerfunc.bind(this)`.

This issue is address on the MDN page for [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). See "The value of this within the handler".

A quick way to work around it would be:

```
var handler = this.listenerfunc.bind(this);
nicediv.addEventListener('tap', handler, false);
...
nicediv.removeEventListener('tap', handler);
```

But you need to keep a reference to `handler` around if you are removing the listener in another scope from where you are adding it.

The way I would fix it is to go to the definition of `this.listenerfunc` and put the `.bind(this)` right on the definition!